# Javascript - Handling redirect Json response

Tags: javascript, java, json, redirect

I have a small login form for an application I am working and I have a ajax request to a servlet that redirects to a new page (After Login is successful).

So basically this is the code in the Java class which theoretically works.

Code included as requested for JAVA CLASS:

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
response.sendRedirect("http://stackoverflow.com/");
try {
out.println(response);
out.flush();
} finally {
out.close();
}}
```

And this is the javacript code which is part of a function called when login button is pressed

Code included as requested for JAVASCRIPT:

```
var prmVlr = {};    
prmVlr["op"] = '2';
prmVlr["userLogin"]=userName;
prmVlr["passLogin"]=hash;
prmVlr["country"]=country;
prmVlr["database"]="CRM";
$j.ajax({type: "GET", url: "LoginHandler",
data:prmVlr,traditional:true,dataType: "json",   cache:false}).done(function(response){
var data=response;
if (data.redirect) {
// data.redirect contains the string URL to redirect to
window.location.href = data.redirect;
}
})
.fail(function(){showMsgAlert('Error'+' - PP-E1003');}); }
```

The idea is when I have developed the next page within the app the user will be redirected to that one.
Also it's the first time I'm working with this so I am not sure if I'm doing this correctly at all. I could return the URL in a string json and then redirect but I am not sure if that will mess up the session.
Also I'm sorry if I'm not explicit enough or I broke some rule here I am new to this site and english is not my main language.

**SOLUTION 1:**
So i came up with a solution it might not be the best but it works.

**On the SERVLET side:**

```
System.out.println(login.getSession_id());
StringBuilder jsonStr = new StringBuilder();
jsonStr.append("{'redirect':'" +          (request.getRequestURI().substring(0,request.getRequestURI().indexOf('/', 1))+"MYPAGELOCATION") +"'}");
jsonResponse = jsonStr.toString().replaceAll("'",
                                Character.toString((char) 34));
```

**On the JAVASCRIPT side:**

```
$j.ajax({type: "GET", url: "LoginHandler",     data:prmVlr,traditional:true,dataType: "json",   cache:false}).done(function(response){
window.location.href = response.redirect;
     }
```

I dont know what will happen to the Session after this as i am still  coding the class. I couldn't figure out why response was not working maybe it was because my login form was calling a javascript function wich encoded the password and then requested the login function on the SERVLET side.

Comment: Please include the code in the question. The images may be deleted in the future from postimg.org and the question would be useless. Thanks!

Comment: I removed images and added code , thank you

Comment: Typically you would issue a POST and have the server side perform the redirect.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get.

Comment: Thank you , i have changed the form to post and changed the response type. Now i can see the url by inspecting the element using firefox i get something like this "GET XHR http:localhost:8080/thepage" and he finds it but still doesnt redirect me from the current page to the new page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i have tested **SOLUTION1** and it works perfectly no problems with sessions or functionalities of the application.

This is how it looks now:

**Javascript**:

```
$j.ajax({type: "GET", url: "LoginHandler",   data:prmVlr,traditional:true,dataType: "json",  cache:false}).done(function(response){
if(response.valido=="1"){ //send 1 if login is valid
     window.location.href = response.redirect;
}
else {
    alert("ERRO NO LOGIN");

}
})
.fail(function(){showMsgAlert('Error'+' - PP-E1003');}); 
}
```

**Java Servlet:**

```
String valido="0";
try {

if (allowUser(userName, passWord,login.getDbUsr())) {
session = request.getSession();
valido="1";
session.setAttribute("logon.isDone", userName);
if ((UsersRegistados.getUsers().containsKey(
request.getRequestedSessionId()) ||   UsersRegistados.getUsers().containsValue(userName))) {
System.out.println("user already registered");
                            }
                        else{
                        UsersRegistados.setUsers(session.getId(), userName);
                        login.setFile(DB.toLowerCase()+"pp"); //crmpp file
                        login.setUcode(userCode); // ep_code
                        login.setUsername(userName); //epName
                        login.setUserType(userType);
                        login.setIdiom(language); 
                        login.setPassword(passWord);
                        login.setSession_id(session.getId());
                         //Try redirecting the client to the page he first tried to access
                         session.setAttribute("login", login); 
                         session.setAttribute("language", language.toUpperCase());
                        }
                   //response.sendRedirect(request.getRequestURI().substring(0,request.getRequestU    RI().indexOf('/', 1))+"/Calendar/calendar.jsp");
//response.setStatus(response.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY);
//response.setHeader("Location",  "Calendar/calendar.jsp");
//System.out.println(jsonResponse);
                    }


                    System.out.println(login.getSession_id());
                    StringBuilder jsonStr = new StringBuilder();
                    jsonStr.append("{'redirect':'" + (request.getRequestURI().substring(0,request.getRequestURI().indexOf('/', 1))+"/Calendar/calendar.jsp") +"','valido':'"+valido+"'}");
                    jsonResponse = jsonStr.toString().replaceAll("'",
                            Character.toString((char) 34));
                    try {
                        out.println(jsonResponse);
                        out.flush();
                    } finally {
                        out.close();                    
 //response.sendRedirect(request.getRequestURI().substring(0,request.getRequestURI().indexOf('/', 1))+"/Calendar/calendar.jsp");
//return;
}
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SQLException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
```